# R Shiny and Markdown - custom css font in pdf

Tags: css, r, shiny, latex, r-markdown

I have used the `gfonts` package to download a css file which contains a custom font for use in my Shiny app. The app has a reporting function, that generates a RMarkdown PDF.  Is there anyway to add this custom .css file that's in the www folder to set the font of the RMarkdown PDF?  I am struggling to find a solution.

```
---
title: "Tool Report "
author: "Me"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: pdf_document
  css: montserrat.css
params: 
  planName: NA
  bYear: NA
  whed: NA
  imp: NA
  red: NA
  plotsummary: NA
fontsize: 10pt
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[justification=raggedright,labelfont=bf,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
   - \let\Begin\begin
   - \let\End\end
---
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was very simple.  [LaTeX has all of the information you need.](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/montserratregular/)

All I had to do was add this to the header:

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat} %% Option 'defaultfam'
```